Detect predetermined objects in 3D
I have a set of slices that together make up a 3D volume. In this volume a number N objects are present. These are all the same kind of objects, say spheroids that can be approximated with a mathematical formula. Is it possible through image analysis to detect these objects, their coordinates and orientation? Follow-up (might be pushing my luck here): is it also possible to label each individual object?
